# wordpress displaying caption on image

Tags: php

I'm trying to do my own slider. I'm almost done but I need my link url to be shown as a title or something.

What should i add to get the link and display?
That's my code

```
<?php
  // The Loop
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?><li>

          <?php 
           // Check if there's a Slide URL given and if so let's a link to it
              if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'wptuts_slideurl', true) ); ?>">

          <?php }
            // The Slide's Image
              echo the_post_thumbnail();

            // Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
              if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
              </a> <?php } ?> </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing the URL from the database as a string, which is placed in the `<a>` tag. That means you can echo it anywhere. Try something like this:

```
// Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
  </a>
  // Add a <span> element which includes the exact same url as your link
  <span class="your-slide-url">
    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'wptuts_slideurl', true); ?>
  </span>
<?php } ?>
```

Now you can just style the `<span class="your-slide-url">` however you like.

Comment: yea! thanks i did it  myself, but i added second field form so i can give link and custom name to it ;) but its exactly how you said ;)